# play 2.1.x - play console can't import utils.xxx subpackages

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use Play console to test some of my classes. The class I wanted to test is in `utils.healing` package (`utils.healing.LowercaseEmailsFix`).

However, play console fails to import sub-packages for utils.xxx classes. Curiously enough it sees it but can't import. Here is a console output:

```
scala> import utils._  
import utils._

scala> import utils.  (pressing Tab+Tab here to get subfolders)
EmailSender           I18nHelper      JsonSerializers          healing           

scala> import utils.healing._
<console>:20: error: object healing is not a member of package play.core.utils
       import utils.healing._
          ^
```

Looks like Play console confuses it with `play.core.utils` package. Is there a way to make it work or is it just a bug? It's Play 2.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
import _root_.utils.healing._
```